# Image uploaded from gallery doesn't show in ImageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I'm aware that there are several other questions on this topic but none of the solutions worked for me. I have added permissions in my manifest. I am able to open the gallery pick a photo and return to the application but the imageView does not change. The app is doing some processing and I am not getting any errors. I have tried also tried to scale the image before inserting it into my imageview with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
public class UserDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
private Context context;
private ImageView imageView;
private Bitmap uploadedImage;
public static final int RESULT_IMAGE = 0;


public UserDetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context =  getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_details, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(filePath).openStream();
            uploadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(uploadedImage);
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my imageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/user_details_icon"
    android:id="@+id/profile_picture" />
```

**EDIT**

I tried to use Picasso instead but still no luck:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){


        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                .resize(10, 10)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);

    }
```

Comment: First, **never catch an `Exception` without logging it**, as you are `onActivityResult()`. Second, your `onActivityResult()` code is wrong, as you may not have rights to work with the file path (e.g., it points to removable storage) and you are doing disk I/O on the main application thread. Use an [image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), passing it the `Uri`, to both use the `Uri` properly and to populate your `ImageView` asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am fairly new to Android so I didn't actually know about Picasso. I'm not sure I understand what you mean regarding the onActivityResult() but I tried changing it to internal storage instead but still no luck. I also changed my entire onActivityResult(see edit) but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

In Your previous code, the problem is in the following lines:

```
InputStream in = new URL(filePath).openStream();
uploadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

these lines are creating exception because that is responsible for downloading image from server and covert it into Bitmap. As you are picking image from local storage, the path of image is something like following

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170209_183830841.jpg

when you pass it in **new URL()** as a parameter, it creates following exception

> java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

In your case first of all you need to add **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission in your manifest file and in **onActivityResult()**, you have to replace

```
InputStream in = new URL(filePath).openStream();
uploadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

with

```
 File image = new File(filePath);
 BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
 bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), true);
```

Note: In case of marshmallow, don't forget to add security permission in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use Picasso instead but still no luck:

That is because you are not using the correct `Uri`. You are using a `Uri` that points to the entire collection of scanned media.

If you read [the documentation for `ACTION_PICK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK), it has:

> Output: The URI of the item that was picked.

Here, the `Uri` in question is obtained by calling `getData()` on the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`.

So, replace `.load(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)` with `.load(data.getData())`.

Also, most likely, you need to increase the size of the image, as a 10px x 10px image is going to be rather small.

Comment: Now I'm getting

E/MiniThumbFile: Unable to create .thumbnails directory /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails

Comment: @Andypandy: Make sure that you have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as a permission, including handling runtime permissions if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher.

Comment: I have added permissions for both reading and writing external storage in my manifest. my target sdk is 19

Comment: @Andypandy: Are you testing on hardware or an emulator? If you are testing on a emulator, did you configure it to have some external storage? Otherwise, I have no idea why `MediaStore` would have difficulty creating that directory.

Comment: I am testing on hardware :)

Comment: @Andypandy: Then I do not know why you are getting that error message, sorry.